# "Select Startup Item" command / drop-down not showing on Standard toolbar in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, ide

Up until recently I could select the startup project (equivalent to right-clicking on the project in the solution explorer and choosing "Set as Startup Project") from the Standard toolbar with the "Select Startup Item" drop-down.  Now it's gone, yet the item is still checked under "Add or Remove Buttons".

The closest reference I could find is [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/373582/select-startup-item-not-showing-in-standard-toolba.html), but the solution doesn't match my situation because I have more than one project and this is happening no matter which solution is loaded.

Please help me figure out what is going on.

[image]

Comment: Me facing same issue. Do you reported this bug?

Comment: No I did not.  .

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 and still this same bug. Sometimes "Startup Project" combobox simply disappears. So i end up in an endless cycle of restarting and resetting the panel and setting startup project from project menu... :(

Answer (score 5):

Open the "Add or Remove Buttons" dropdown in the section with the "Start" button, deselect "Startup Projects" and close all Visual Studio windows.  Open a new instance of Visual Studio and re-enable "Startup Projects."  It should show up for you then.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. The "Startup Projects" drop-down disappeared occasionally. It was probably caused by installing/uninstallin/updating VS extensions.

The solution was easy. Install free extension [Clear MEF Component Cache](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ClearMEFComponentCache). Then simply click the **Clear MEF Component Cache** in the **Tools** menu. The toolbar should be repaired after restating Visual Studio.

This solution does NOT reset any of your UI customizations.

Comment: This worked for me with vs2022, the cache folder to delete is %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<vs version>\ComponentModelCache if you want to delete is manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the start menu item (called "Debug Target") was completely gone. Toggling the menu item on and off did not resolve the issue. I selected "Reset Toolbar" at the bottom of the menu and that resolved the problem for me. May require some manual set up after if your menu is heavily customized. But if you use the Standard layout it shouldn't be an issue.

[image: Reset Toolbar Option]

Comment: Nah, not working.